# Firebase No properties to serialize found with object in release mode

Tags: java, android, object, firebase, release-mode

I've written a method for pushing real-time location data to Firebase:

```
private void writeNewMarker(int sessionType, String myUuid, String datetime, Location location) {
    locationToDB = new LocationFromAndroid();
    JSONObject jsonObjectCoords = new Coords(location.getLatitude() + "", location.getLongitude() + "", location.getAltitude() + "");
    locationToDB.setFinish("false");
    locationToDB.setLost("false");
    locationToDB.setCoords(jsonObjectCoords);
    locationToDB.setDistanceToGo("0");
    locationToDB.setHeading(location.getBearing() + "");
    locationToDB.setNauwkeurigheid(location.getAccuracy() + "");
    locationToDB.setSpeed(location.getSpeed() * 3.6 + "");
    locationToDB.setSpeed2(location.getSpeed() + "");
    locationToDB.setTimestamp(location.getTime() + "");
    locationToDB.setWp_user(myUuid);
    locationToDB.setSessionType(sessionType);
    locationToDB.setTitle(title);
    if(myUuid != null && datetime != null && locationToDB.getTitle() != null && !myUuid.isEmpty() && !datetime.isEmpty()) {
        databaseRef.child(myUuid + "-Android" + sessionType + datetime).setValue(locationToDB);
```

When I'm building the app in debug mode, it works perfectly fine. But when I'm building it in Release mode for Google Play, it stops working at this line:

```
databaseRef.child(myUuid + "-Android" + sessionType + datetime).setValue(locationToDB);
```

To be more specific: When I'm doing this, everything is OK:

```
databaseRef.child(myUuid + "-Android" + sessionType + datetime).setValue("Test");
```

It does look like passing an object as value isn't possible within a signed APK?

**Error:**
Exception com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class

Comment: Have you configured ProGuard as described in the [Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/#proguard)?

Comment: Adding `-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
  *;
}` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @BartRos please can you explain this why we are doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding `-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** { *; }` in proguard-rules.pro did the trick.

[Proguard Rules Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/#proguard)