# No properties to serialize found on class com.contentful.vault.Asset

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, contentful, contentful-vault

Am getting this error while trying to save an Object on the `Firebase` database that has an `Asset` property.
Similar errors have been documented in the following questions:

[Firebase No properties to serialize found on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743661/firebase-no-properties-to-serialize-found-on-class)

[Firebase No properties to serialize found with object in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473498/firebase-no-properties-to-serialize-found-with-object-in-release-mode)

and a few others.

Some of the solutions recommended are to

1. Change variable declarations to public
2. Add `@Keep` to the class declaration
3. Add `-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** { *; }` in Proguard-rules

but none of these options have worked for me.

What I've tried is create another class that is a replica of the class am using for `Vault` and then have a `String` property that holds the `URL` of the `Asset` but this seems like duplication of code and unnecessary.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I am Mario Bodemann, a maintainer of the Java and Android SDKs of Contentful.

I would recommend separating the concerns between the Firebase use-case and the Contentful use-case, as you suggested too.

This way you can make sure to provide Firebase with a model that it needs and Contentful with a model that it needs, without intermixing both. I don't see it as repeating code, you are repeating data. And that should be alright for different use-cases.

Probably some factories for converting from one form to the other on a per need basis would be convenient too.

Otherwise, maybe if you could share a bit more about your use of both in one app, we could be able to help you a bit more...

Greetings,
Mario

Comment: Thanks Mario, I think I'll stick with having separate classes for Contentful and Firebase.