# Firestore : No properties to serialize found on class

Tags: android, android-proguard

***Note:***

Please don't mark this question as a duplicate as I have already gone through similar questions and their answers.

***Error :***

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.appz.abhi.shudhbatter.b.c
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.l$a.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.l.a(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.l.b(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.l.b(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.l.a(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.ah.b(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.a(Unknown Source)
>           at com.appz.abhi.shudhbatter.view.onboarding.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
>           at com.appz.abhi.shudhbatter.view.onboarding.a.a.a.lambda$56b6vrtW7GJri_HgEDiOk1aRbrY(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.appz.abhi.shudhbatter.view.onboarding.a.a.-$$Lambda$a$56b6vrtW7GJri_HgEDiOk1aRbrY.onClick(lambda)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

***Similar Questions:***

1. [Firebase No properties to serialize found on class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37743661/9636037)
2. [No properties to serialize found on class com.contentful.vault.Asset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46443914/9636037)
3. [Firebase No properties to serialize found with object in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44473498/9636037)
4. [Firebase - No properties to serialize found on class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46254266/9636037)

***proguard-rules.pro:***

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}

# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { *; }

# Keep custom model classes
-keepclassmembers class com.mypackage.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.util.** { *; }
```

Using the mapping file, I found the error to be caused by the following model class:

***User.java:***

```
package com.mypackage.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {

    //  Data
    private Long phone;
    private String uid, name, mail, apartmentName, doorNo;
    private UserType userType;

    public User() {
        userType = UserType.USER;
    }

    public Long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getApartmentName() {
        return apartmentName;
    }

    public void setApartmentName(String apartmentName) {
        this.apartmentName = apartmentName;
    }

    public String getDoorNo() {
        return doorNo;
    }

    public void setDoorNo(String doorNo) {
        this.doorNo = doorNo;
    }

    public UserType getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
}
```

***UserType.java:***

```
package com.mypackage.model;

public enum UserType {
    USER, ADMIN, DELIVERY
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above error was resolved after doing the following:

1. Clean and rebuild project.
2. Removing all proguard rules.
3. Adding `@Keep` in each model class beginning.